# Form File Upload Field generates multiple copies of Image Files (different sizes): Is this a WP feature or is this being done by the Plugin

Tags: images, uploads

During the building of Forms that needed to capture user files, I noticed that image files (gif, jpg, etc) appeared to be automatically multiplying (files were automatically being generated with various aspect sizes) ... as part of an email submission process, only one of these files was expected to be attached to a submission email ... in order to accomplish this, had to add a custom file filter to eliminate all but one of any of these files.

Now needing to do some investigation, as ALL of these size variation files appear to be being ignored by the aforementioned filter, ending up on the submission emails.

Would be nice to know:

- where these files are being generated; WP or Plugin
- whether there is a way of turning OFF this "FEATURE"

I suspect there may have been a file naming convention change in recent releases of either the Form Plugin or WP ... will know more once I review the custom filter code which after several years (even with comments) seems alien

Comment: WordPress creates multiple versions of images that are in the media library. Are your images ending up there?

Comment: I have downloaded the entire WP folder, subfolders & files so I can use my old Ztree search tools to narrow down this issue ... what I have determined is VFB makes a call to wp_generate_attachement_metadata which in turn calls the WP function wp_update_image_subsizes ... this answers the question of WHAT code is generating these files ... looking at the actual WP code doesn't reveal any FLAGS to stop/bypass this process ... so still trying to understand what might have changed ... prior to the 4 major updates, even though subsized files were generated, only one file per upld was ever exported.

Comment: Had a struggle initially with how the metafile records are stored in the database ... expecting that the query I used for processing these records will need to be revisited and possibly tweaked

Comment: ... VFB provides a GDPR option that goes too far as it completely wipes out all Form data and Files ... part of the metafile processing is tied into code which I used to modify this GDPR feature ... ultimately key details like; Post ID, Date, Time, Form ID, and email-to, all needed to be retained for transaction/audit purpose ... plus ... ensuring all the metafile data & files are removed along with only one instance of any uploaded file being exported took some mental effort a few years back ... my code comments while likely making sense at the time are making me kick myself now.

Comment: In a perfect world, this process should only be exporting one instance of a medium-scaled image file ... an example of the file sizes being generated are; 150x150, 296x176, 300x225, 406x300, 454x332, 624x468, 640x358 ... looking at the WP code, these values appear to be calculated based on the Height and Width Meta Data found in the uploaded image file

Comment: If the images are being added as attachments then the additional files referred. That’s why there’s no ‘flag’. If you don’t want the images to be attachments that’s something you need to take up with the plugin author.